# Python Publisher and C++ Subscriber problem

Tags: ros, python, c++, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
we cannot get any information, when we try to connect our C++ listener to the existing, working Python Publisher. Codes are given below.

Publisher

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('razor_imu_9dof')
import rospy

import serial
import string
import math

from time import time, sleep
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
from razor_imu_9dof.msg import RazorImu


import tf

grad2rad = 3.141592/180.0

rospy.init_node("node")
pub = rospy.Publisher('imu', Imu)
pubRaw = rospy.Publisher('imuRaw', RazorImu)
#print pubRaw

#epub = rospy.Publisher('imuRaw', Imu)

imuMsg = Imu()
imuRawMsg = RazorImu()
imuMsg.orientation_covariance = [999999 , 0 , 0,
0, 9999999, 0,
0, 0, 999999]
imuMsg.angular_velocity_covariance = [9999, 0 , 0,
0 , 99999, 0,
0 , 0 , 0.02]
imuMsg.linear_acceleration_covariance = [0.2 , 0 , 0,
0 , 0.2, 0,
0 , 0 , 0.2]

default_port='/dev/ttyUSB0'
port = rospy.get_param('device', default_port)
# Check your COM port and baud rate
ser = serial.Serial(port=port,baudrate=57600, timeout=1)

#f = open("Serial"+str(time())+".txt", 'w')

roll=0
pitch=0
yaw=0
rospy.sleep(5) # Sleep for 8 seconds to wait for the board to boot then only write command.
ser.write('#ox' + chr(13)) # To start display angle and sensor reading in text 
while 1:
    line = ser.readline()
    line = line.replace("#YPR=","")
    line = line.replace("#YPRAMG=","")   # Delete "#YPR="
    #f.write(line)                     # Write to the output log file
    words = string.split(line,",")    # Fields split
    #wort5 = float(words[5]) 
    #print wort3, wort4, wort5

    if len(words) > 2:
        try:
            yaw = float(words[0])*grad2rad
            pitch = -float(words[1])*grad2rad
            roll = -float(words[2])*grad2rad
            
            # Publish message
            imuMsg.linear_acceleration.x = float(words[3]) # tripe axis accelerator meter
            imuMsg.linear_acceleration.y = float(words[4])
            imuMsg.linear_acceleration.z = float(words[5])
        #print imuMsg.linear_acceleration.x, imuMsg.linear_acceleration.y ,imuMsg.linear_acceleration.z

        #epub.publish(imuMsg)
            
            imuMsg.angular_velocity.x = float(words[9]) #gyro
            imuMsg.angular_velocity.y = float(words[10]) 
            imuMsg.angular_velocity.z = float(words[11])
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            
        q = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll,pitch,yaw)
        imuMsg.orientation.x = q[0] #magnetometer
        imuMsg.orientation.y = q[1]
        imuMsg.orientation.z = q[2]
        imuMsg.orientation.w = q[3]
    #time.sleep( 2 )
    #print imuMsg.orientation.x, imuMsg.orientation.y, imuMsg.orientation.z, imuMsg.orientation.w
        imuMsg.header.stamp= rospy.Time.now()
        imuMsg.header.frame_id = 'base_link'
        pub.publish(imuMsg)
    print imuMsg #Gibt alle Sensorwerte in einer Art Tabelle aus

            
        # Publish Raw message from Razor board
        imuRawMsg.yaw = yaw
        imuRawMsg.pitch = pitch
        imuRawMsg.roll = roll
        pubRaw.publish(imuRawMsg)
    #print imuRawMsg

        
ser.close
#f.close
```

Subscriber

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"


void chatterIMU(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("imu", 1000, chatterIMU);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

Could you please say, what we do wrong. According to this tutorial `http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSNodeTutorialC%2B%2BPython` subscriber/publisher does not depend on the source language, as we understood. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66026/python-publisher--and-c++-subscriber--problem/) by [roman27](https://answers.ros.org/users/5118/roman27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right: it doesn't depend on the source language.

First of all, you're publishing an imu message, but you're subscribing to a std_msgs::String.  It'll probably fuss at you for that.

Once you fix the message types to be the same, I'd suggest using the [rostopic command line tool](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostopic) to echo what your publisher is publishing and publish dummy messages to your subscriber.  That way you can test and debug the nodes independently.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4